# Cantor function preserves Borel set

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $f:C\to [0,1]$ and $C$ is the Cantor set with subspace topology $\tau_C$ and $f$ is the Cantor function, i.e. take the ternary only with 0,2 on bits and maps to binary with 0, 1.

How can I show $K\subseteq[0,1]$ is Borel if and only if $f^{-1}(K)$ is? Actually, I want to show with the subset topology, i.e. for all $K\in \mathfrak{B}(\tau_{[0,1]})$, if and only if $f^{-1}(K)\in \mathfrak{B}(\tau_{C})$.

And is this equivalent to $f(K)\subseteq[0,1]$ is Borel if and only if $f(K)$ is?

Comment: Show that if you omit countably many points, the remaining map is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Is Cantor set homeomorphic to [0,1]?

Comment: No, the Cantor set minus a countable set is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ minus a countable set.

Comment: Which set of points? Isn't f already bijective and continuous?

Comment: @CO2 Which set of points is indeed what you need to think about.

Comment: No, not bijective.  In binary, $0.0\overline{1}$ and $0.1\overline{0}$ are equal, but in ternary, $0.0\overline{2}$ and $0.2\overline{0}$ are not equal.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I found a remark online (not here) stating that, in general for the Cantor function $C: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$, if $B\subset[0,1]$ is Borel, then $C(A) \in \mathcal{B}$

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Cantor function is a measurable function. Every continuous function is measurable, every monotone function, too: for a continuous function, the pre-image of an open set is open, for a monotone function, the pre-image of an interval is an interval. Both intervals and open sets generate the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets. And the Cantor function is both monotone and continuous.